# The role of Google Protocol Buffers in network software

Tags: java, serialization, tcp, netty, protocol-buffers

**Edit**: Here I'm talking about the Java binding of Protocol Buffers.

I'm trying to understand what Google Protocol Buffers are and what they do. Let's say I have a simple Netty-based network client/server pair. The client randomly sends `Ping` messages to the server, and the server responds with a `Pong` message.

How would Protocol Buffers fit into the equation here? Would I use them to serialize `Ping` and `Pong` messages, and then use Netty to do the actual transport of those serialized messages? Or does Protocol Buffers take care of the transport as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The public protocol-buffers drop only includes a specification for serialization. Some teasing and tempting hooks in place hinting at a full RPC stack, but no implementation or specification is provided. If you are using protocol-buffers, you will need your own transport or RPC stack, or a library that adds these features for you. To emphasize: all that protocol-buffers formally declares is a serialization protocol and a DSL that describes data to be stored in that format.

Comment: Thanks @Marc Gravell (+1) - so you are saying that, in the case of Java, that I would need to use the Java binding for protocol buffers, yes? If so, how does your answer change if we are talking about the actual Java implementation? Thanks again!

Comment: @IAmYourFaja there are, iirc, multiple java implementations of protobuf. Any should work identically for serialization purposes. If one or more offers RPC services, then that's fine but no protocol is defined, so there is no guarantee of compatibility with any particular system